# Show selected items only from DropDownCheckBoxes using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down with checkbox and i want to show only the selected items but my issue is that it is showing twice for the same item.  For example, if i select item #4 and #7, it will show like this 4 4, 7 7.  How can i show only unique values for the selected items from the drop down?

```
string myList = string.Empty;
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in facDDL.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
         myList += item.Text + " " + item.Value + ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using both Text and Value.

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value(v=vs.110).aspx

You will better understand the effect by changing the content of your drop down to :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="UserSelectionDropDownControl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Five</asp:ListItem>                
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In this case when selection the fourth row in the list item, your string will be

> Four 4,

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you never supply a Key Value pair as the ListItem properties.

If you do this on the aspx page

```
<asp:ListItem>Text</asp:ListItem>
```

both the Key and Value are the same. So you must change that to

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Value" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
```

If you are binding data in code behind, make sure you specify the Key and Value colums.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = mySource;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Or when adding one at a time from code behind

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Text", "Value", true));
```

Answer (score 0):

all what i did is to replace this

```
myList += item.Text + " " + item.Value + ",";
```

with this

```
 myList += "'" + item.Value + "', ";
```

and it worked like a charm.
thanks